# How to use a url from a json formatted answer with the get_url module?

Tags: json, rest, ansible

I am requesting a REST API to provide me with a download url for a specific item (this is solved by the uri-module). I then try to use the url in the get_url module but it fails with the following message

`FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ cora_response.json.['@odata.mediaReadLink'].stdout | from_json }}"}`

How am i suppose to put the variable into the url parameter?
My task looks currently like this:

```
- name: Download Link from REST
   debug: var=cora_response.json['@odata.mediaReadLink']

- name: Download the latest Release
  get_url:
    url: "{{ cora_response.json.['@odata.mediaReadLink'].stdout | from_json }}"
    dest: "{{ installation_path }}/install/19.3.zip"
    mode: 660
```

My debug task shows me the url i am trying to use, however the get_url module fails.

Please advise and thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
Tried the following suggested by @al76

```
- name: Download the latest CH Release
  get_url:
    url: "{{ cora_response.json['@odata.mediaReadLink'].stdout | from_json }}"
    dest: "{{ installation_path }}/install/CH19.3.zip"
    mode: 660
```

*Error message:*

```
fatal: [ln-lnxcelcon01.owo.company]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cora_response.json['@odata.mediaReadLink'].stdout | from_json }}): expected string or buffer"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blind luck took me out of my misery

```
url: "{{ cora_response.json['@odata.mediaReadLink'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
url: "{{ cora_response.json['@odata.mediaReadLink'].stdout | from_json }}"
```

Comment: Same exact problem